# html page with css and bootstrap not rendering cards consistently

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a basic bootstrap and html page with css, and while the first 'card' is being rendered correctly, all the other ones, are different sizes.
Oddly, and perhaps this is a clue as to the solution, when the size of the page is reduced (e.g. to mobile size) then all the cards are the same size as desired.

Could anyone suggest a fix to ensure all the cards are the same size when at full page size?

```html
 <section class="site-hero overlay page-inside" style="background-image: url(img/thames_backdrop.jpg)">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row site-hero-inner justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <h1 class="heading" data-aos="fade-up">Browse</h1>
            <p class="sub-heading mb-5" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">West End</p>
           
          </div> 
        </div>
        <!-- <a href="#" class="scroll-down">Scroll Down</a> -->
      </div>
    </section>

   
            
         <div class="card_container">
          <div class="card_row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
          <section class="room">
      <!-- Room Image -->
      <div class="room_img">
        <img src="img/11_Cadogan_Gardens.jpg">
      </div>
      <!-- Room Information -->
      <div class="room_information">
        <h2 class="room_information--heading">Hotel1</h2>
        <p>Stylish town house hotel with a member's club atmosphere.</p>
        <a href="#" class="room_information--moreinfo-btn js-room_moreinfo_btn">+ more information</a>
      </div>
      <div class="room_moreinfo js-room_moreinfo" style="display: none;">
        <p id="quote">
          Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe
          al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. Ma quande lingues coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue es
          plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent lingues.
        </p>

        <p>
          Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan lingues. It va esser tam simplic quam Occidental in fact, it va esser Occidental. A un Angleso it va semblar un simplificat Angles, quam un skeptic Cambridge amico dit me que
          Occidental es.Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun
          vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /Room more information section-->

      <div class="room_features">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-bath"></i>&nbsp;WC</li>
          <!-- Bath Icon -->
          <li><i class="fa fa-male"></i>&nbsp;1-3</li>
          <!-- People Icon -->
          <li><span class="room_features--price">170.-</span><small class="room_features--currency">CHF</small></li>
          <!-- Price -->
        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="room_features--book-btn">Book Now</a>
        <!-- Book now -->
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>


<div class="card_container">
  <div class="card_row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <section class="room">
      <!-- Room Image -->
      <div class="room_img">
        <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/w9k7s5h89/hotel_thumb_2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <!-- Room Information -->
      <div class="room_information">
        <h2 class="room_information--heading">45 Park Lane</h2>
        <p>Dramatic art-deco styling and exceptional friendly service.</p>
        <a href="#" class="room_information--moreinfo-btn js-room_moreinfo_btn">+ more information</a>
      </div>
      <div class="room_moreinfo js-room_moreinfo" style="display: none;">
        <p>
          Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe
          al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. Ma quande lingues coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue es
          plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent lingues.
        </p>

        <p>
          Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan lingues. It va esser tam simplic quam Occidental in fact, it va esser Occidental. A un Angleso it va semblar un simplificat Angles, quam un skeptic Cambridge amico dit me que
          Occidental es.Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun
          vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /Room more information section-->

      <div class="room_features">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-utensils-alt">&nbsp;</i></li>
          <!-- Bath Icon -->
          <li><i class="fa fa-male"></i>&nbsp;1-3</li>
          <!-- People Icon -->
          <li><span class="room_features--price">130.-</span><small class="room_features--currency">CHF</small></li>
          <!-- Price -->
        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="room_features--book-btn">Book Now</a>
        <!-- Book now -->
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!-- /row-->
</div>
<!-- /container -->   

<!-- New card -->

<div class="card_row">
    <section class="room">
      <!-- Room Image -->
      <div class="room_img">
        <img src="https://s26.postimg.org/w9k7s5h89/hotel_thumb_2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <!-- Room Information -->
      <div class="room_information">
        <h2 class="room_information--heading">45 Park Hotel</h2>
        <p>Dramatic art-deco styling and exceptional friendly service.</p>
        <a href="#" class="room_information--moreinfo-btn js-room_moreinfo_btn">+ more information</a>
      </div>
      <div class="room_moreinfo js-room_moreinfo" style="display: none;">
        <p>
          Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. Omnicos directe
          al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles. Ma quande lingues coalesce, li grammatica del resultant lingue es
          plu simplic e regulari quam ti del coalescent lingues.
        </p>

        <p>
          Li nov lingua franca va esser plu simplic e regulari quam li existent Europan lingues. It va esser tam simplic quam Occidental in fact, it va esser Occidental. A un Angleso it va semblar un simplificat Angles, quam un skeptic Cambridge amico dit me que
          Occidental es.Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun
          vocabules. Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar custosi traductores. At solmen va esser necessi far uniform grammatica, pronunciation e plu sommun paroles.
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- /Room more information section-->

      <div class="room_features">
        <ul>
          <li><i class="fa fa-bath"></i>&nbsp;WC</li>
          <!-- Bath Icon -->
          <li><i class="fa fa-male"></i>&nbsp;1-3</li>
          <!-- People Icon -->
          <li><span class="room_features--price">130.-</span><small class="room_features--currency">CHF</small></li>
          <!-- Price -->
        </ul>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="room_features--book-btn">Book Now</a>
        <!-- Book now -->
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <!-- /row-->
</div>

<!-- New card -->
```

Comment: add your images on that

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Add images in your code or show us live example in codepen or jsfiddle !!